# Unittest TestLoader discover() does not reload test suite when the suite is changed

Tags: python, unit-testing

This is the program which discovers test suite in the repository`tests/` and run the test cases.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        c = raw_input("input: ")
        if c == "T":
            suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover("tests")
            result_file = open("results", "w")
            unittest.TextTestRunner(result_file).run(suite)
            result_file.close()
            result_file = open("results", "r")
            output = result_file.read()
            print output
```

This is the test suite under the repository`tests/`

```
class TestFileFail(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_fail(self):
        self.fail("Fail")
        # self.assertTrue(True)
```

I find that the test suite does not reload when I edit the test cases. Only when I reload the program can it discover the change. For example, I get the result like this when I run the program:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

If I change the test case to:

```
# self.fail("Fail")
self.assertTrue(True)
```

the result remains the same and only when I reload the program can I get the right result:

```
Ran 1 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

But why is that?

Answer (score 0):

This is because all test modules are imported with Python's import system, which caches imported modules in the [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) dict so changes made to a module after the initial import won't be reflected upon repeated imports.

To force the test runner to re-import all test modules, you can keep a copy of of the original `sys.modules` and restore it after the test runner finishes:

```
modules = sys.modules.copy() # note here
while True:
    c = input("input: ")
    if c == "T":
        suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover("tests")
        result_file = open("results", "w")
        unittest.TextTestRunner(result_file).run(suite)
        result_file.close()
        result_file = open("results", "r")
        output = result_file.read()
        print(output)
        sys.modules = modules.copy() # note here
```